# how to implement ping pong in java spring websocket

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, ping, spring-websocket

As per the documentation here https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#page-37,
a `websocket` must respond to a `ping` request with `pong`.

I have implemented `spring boot websocket` to handle the `websocket` connections from clients.

I have a `websocket` client implemented which sends `ping frames` periodically.

I found it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24438328 that I cannot process ping messages in java.

I have queries regarding this -

1. Should I have to handle these `ping` requests in `java spring-boot websocket`?
2. if yes how could I implement this in spring boot application and respond to a `ping` request with `pong`?

Comment: umm do you need to handle pings by yourself? websocet specification regards protocol and transport layer while you should bother about application level only.

Comment: I dont want to handle it on application level but I wanted the confirmation it it is handled by the library in some of the middle layer. My client is getting disconnected since it is not getting the pong for intended ping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend class `TextWebSocketHandler` and write your logic in `handleTextMessage` method. If you are looking for more generic approach look into `WebSocketHandler` interface. But as Antoniossss suggested ping pong is already implemented on protocol level for checking if connection is still alive.

Comment: I tried this already but here the event for handling the ping frame (`PongMessage/PingMessage/BinaryMessage`) never occurred and it is working well for application level `TextMessage`

Answer (score 6):

> Should I have to handle these ping requests in java spring-boot websocket?

No

The server will automatically reply with a pong.

For Tomcat see

https://github.com/apache/tomcat85/blob/b21d02042c408053a1944b27c3196ec9be3db381/java/org/apache/tomcat/websocket/WsFrameBase.java#L348

https://github.com/apache/tomcat85/blob/b21d02042c408053a1944b27c3196ec9be3db381/java/org/apache/tomcat/websocket/WsFrameBase.java#L41-L42

For Jetty

https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/b0f34fec3f4156c6fb250132fe95a895e07fb5ae/jetty-websocket/websocket-common/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/common/events/AbstractEventDriver.java#L125-L143

The ping is not exposed in the spring websocket handler (receive part)

With jetty it's possible to get notified for the ping (see `org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.WebSocketPingPongListener`)

But it's not used by spring-websocket.