# Java WebSocket PING/PONG

Tags: java, websocket

Java WebSocket client API method:

```
public void sendPong(String message) throws IOException {
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(message.getBytes());
    this.session.getAsyncRemote().sendPong(buffer);
}
```

Java WebSocket server API has method:

```
@OnMessage
public void onMessage(PongMessage message, Session session) throws IOException {
    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Received PONG message: " + new String(message.getApplicationData().array()));
}
```

---

Java WebSocket client API method:

```
public void sendPing(String message) throws IOException {
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(message.getBytes());
    this.session.getAsyncRemote().sendPing(buffer);
}
```

Java WebSocket server API doesn't have a method to accept PING message.

Why we can send a PING message with payload but we cannot accept PING message?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Receiving pings with Java EE Websocket API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24416242/receiving-pings-with-java-ee-websocket-api)